# Google Maps Android API v2: My location marker always over other markers?

Tags: android, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

Currently migrating an Android app using Google Maps to Google Maps Android v2; I want the map to display the built-in location marker, as well as custom markers. 
With the previous library, I used to draw the location marker 'below' custom markers, with

```
mapView.setReticleDrawMode(ReticleDrawMode.DRAW_RETICLE_UNDER);
```

I can't find a similar option in the new API. Did I miss something?

Comment: I think I might have a solution to this. Just notify me if you need it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a bit a searching, I couldn't find such an option.

I finally removed the location pin, and added a similar Marker and Circle to the map; since it is a classic Marker, it appears below the other markers.

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);

// ...
// get the current location with Android LocationManager in some way
// ...

// then draw it on the map when it changes:
if (null == getMyLocation())
    return;

if (null != locationMarker) {
    locationMarker.remove();
}
if (null != locationCircle) {
    locationCircle.remove();
}
LatLng loc = getMyLocation();

locationMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .fromResource(R.drawable.blue_pin_12))
        .position(getMyLocation()).anchor(0.5f, 0.5f));

float accuracy = getMyLocationAccuracy();

locationCircle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(loc)
            .radius(accuracy)
            .strokeColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 153, 255))
            .fillColor(Color.argb(30, 0, 153, 255)).strokeWidth(2));
```

[image: Location pin]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code snippet. But how to get the accuracy??

Comment: what does getMyLocationAccuracy()?

Comment: the API evolved since this 4-years old answer. You can get the accuracy with location.getAccuracy() https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy()