# What's the logic behind marker selection with 2 or more overlapping marker? (Google API android v2)

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

If i make a tap on the map on a marker, an event gets triggered and i can catch it implementing the interface `OnMarkerClickListener. The event return me the marker on which i tapped; this is straightforward. The problem i'm facing now is that when there are 2 or more marker one on top of another, i don't know on which marker will be triggered the event. I already excluded the possibility that the first marker to be drew is the first to be selected and it seems like the choice is made at randoms, but i think this is not the case.

**I would like to know how the API choose on which marker to trigger the event, between the "n" overlapping marker, and how i can control this choice.**

I must say that due to some logic in my app i would like to not use Spinderfier or Marker clustering to avoid Marker overlapping; i also found [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804361/google-maps-android-api-v2-my-location-marker-always-over-other-markers) to eliminate the problem i can't use it.

Sorry for my poor English and thank you for your attention.