# How to place a marker on top of my location layer?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have issue with drawing custom marker on top of marker from  my location layer using GoogleMaps for Android.

[image: my location layer on top of custom marker]

Documentation doesn't provide any information how to do that.
Setting big value for markers `zIndex` doesn't help.

Comment: what have you done that did not work?

Comment: I turned on my location layer using `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` and placed the marker. As you can see in my case marker is below my location. Isn't that default behavior?

Comment: Maybe call `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); ` before `googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);`

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13804361/6950238) question and answer. Seems only one way to do that - disable normal location icon (`map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);`) and draw custom location marker manually (with z-order less than z-order of your markers).

Comment: My Location Marker has a lot of nice features: it shows direction + precision, it will not be so easy to implement. But it seems like the only way.

Comment: It's not as difficult as it seems. And there is only this way.